# assign FileReader result to a (global) variable for later use

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

How can I assign  FileReader.readAsDataURL  result to a (global) variable for later  use?

I know that FileReader.result works asyc and can used in reader.onload = function () {...}  But I was not able to assign it to a global var (from inside the anonymous callback) for later use.

I googled and found some hints also on stackoverflow, but nothing that really helps me. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

app.component.ts:

```ts
export class AppComponent {

  postData: PostData;

  image: File;
  status: string;
  imageBase64: string

  constructor(private http: Http ) {
    this.imageBase64 = '';
  }

  fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    if (fileInput.target.files && fileInput.target.files[0]) {
      let file  = fileInput.target.files[0];
      let preview = document.querySelector('img')

      let reader = new FileReader();

      this.image = file;

      reader.onload = function (e: any) {
        let b64 = e.target.result   

        // this.imageBase64 = b64;  // undefinded here  

        preview.src = b64;
        console.log(file);
        console.log(b64);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(this.image);
    }
}

  uploadimage() {
  // do something later with the bae64 reader.result - after upload button pressed
  }
```

app.component.html:

```html
<label>Choose a file</label> 
<input type="file" class="inputfile" accept="image/*"(change)="fileChangeEvent($event)">
<img id="preview" src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
<button (click)="uploadimage()">Upload Image</button>
```

Comment: try with window.myGlobalVariable where myGlobalVariable could be whatever you decide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have the wrong `this`. Inside of a `function`, `this` is bound dynamically to the object on which the function is called, if it is called as method. If the function is not called as a method, `this` is `undefined` in strict mode (modules and class bodies are implicitly strict) and otherwise it defaults to the global object.

`this` can also be bound to a specific object using `Function.prototype.bind`. When called, function returned by `bind` will resolve this to the specified object.

```
function fullname() {
  return this.first + '_' this.last;
}

const philip = {first: 'Philip', last: 'Pullman'};
const philipsFullname = fullname.bind(philip);
console.log(philipsFullname()); // Philip Pullman
```

`this` can also be set on invocation, without an intermediate object, using `Function.prototype.call`.

```
console.log(fullname.call(philip)); // Philip Pullman
```

Use an arrow function `(params) => expression or block`. Arrow functions statically bind `this`. In all functions everything is statically bound except for this. In arrow functions, everything is statically bound.

```
export class AppComponent {
  fileChangeEvent(fileInput: HTMLInputElement) {

    reader.onload = e => {
      const b64 = e.target.result   
      this.imageBase64 = b64; 

      preview.src = b64;

      console.log(file);
      console.log(b64);
      window.IMAGE_RESULT = b64;
    };
  }
}


declare global {
  interface Window {
    IMAGE_RESULT?: string;
  }
}
```

Comment: @mhoff fixed some confusing wording in this answer. Don't forget to vote for it if it works for you :p

Comment: Aluan thanks for the explanation - exactly what I need and it works. (seems I need to study some basic typescript)
btw: I had to change `e.target.result` to `reader.result`

Comment: @mhoff actually, it is just JavaScript you need to study. This is all JS stuff